# RubyCAS register new users, how to do it, using Devise?

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, cas

I am struggling to register users in rubyCAS-server DB
 
I am using Devise(3.2.2) and devise_cas_authenticatable(1.3.4) as a SSO solution. Using rubyCAS as the server SSO.
I am able to login fine, but my issue is how to register new users.
I want to have two apps that share the same user base, intead of having the users to register in both sides.
But it will be them to go to the website and sign_up.
I would like to use devise because of the built-in and well tested recovery mechanisms, etc.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :cas_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
end
```

After I hit the sign_up button, an error shows on the POST:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
unknown attribute: password
```

If I use database_authenticatable it works fine, so I belive Devise is well configured.
I also have in Devise.config initializer:

```
config.cas_create_user = true
```

I can't find information about registering users on the SSO system. I believe it is the application job to create the users that will be shared among the apps, and I though this should work... am I right?
If not, what would you suggest for this kind of shared users system?

Thank you so much for your help and any suggestions you kindly provide.
Best regards,
Nuno

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this?

Comment: No, I abandoned that idea and I will go for the devise with omniauth enabled. However I didn't need onmiauth yet, because that will be used by secondary webapps and I am still developing the main app.

Answer (score 2):

To register new users with an encrypted password you need to include `DatabaseAuthenticable` module. Add the line below into your user model.

```
include Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using password column we can reuse by using alias_attribute on user model

Example:

alias_attribute :username, :email

alias_attribute :password, :encrypted_password